# partial differential equations and particular solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Diffusion equation, but with the boundary conditions x(0)=1, x(l)=0. I have been told this is impossible, and I understand that this is because when we come to sum the solution using fourier series the infinite sum is the infinite sum of 1 = 1+1+1+......, and hence we cannot find the solution this way.
is there a way of solving it using general and particular solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your equation is of the form
$$
u_t-a^2u_{xx}=0,\quad 0\le x\le \ell,\quad t\ge0,
$$
with initial condition $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ and boundary conditions $u(0,t)=1$, $u(\ell,t)=0$. You cannot apply directly the method of separation of variables because of the boundary condition at $x=0$. But it is possible to solve the equation. Let $h(x)=1-x/\ell$. Then $h$ satisfies the boundary conditions and $h''(x)=0$. Let $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-h(x)$. Then $v$ satisfies the same equation as $u$, initial condition $v(x,0)=u_0(x)-h(x)$  and boundary conditions $v(0,t)=v(\ell,t)=0$. Finally use separation of variables to find $v$.